# (ActiveJpa) Issue with the ActiveJpa 'like' filter

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

The like condition operator in ActiveJpa performs unexpectedly when the comparison string consists of Special Characters.

This is for a REST API built using the Java 8 Dropwizard framework.

```
str = "%"+str+"%"
filter.addCondition("column", Condition.Operator.like, str)
```

Initial thoughts were that ActiveJpa filters out all the special characters. But, the following change also does not work.

```
filter.addCondition("column", Condition.Operator.like, str.replace("+",""))
```

When the following string value is passed,

```
str = "+1212"
```

It returns `null` even if, corresponding results exist.